# How can you translate a flat dotted list of properties to a constructed object?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, recursion

I have a list of properties and their values and they are formatted in a `Dictionary<string, object>` like this:

```
Person.Name = "John Doe"
Person.Age = 27
Person.Address.House = "123"
Person.Address.Street = "Fake Street"
Person.Address.City = "Nowhere"
Person.Address.State = "NH"
```

There are two classes. `Person` is composed of the string `Name` and primitive `Age` as well as the complex `Address` class which has `House`, `Street`, `City`, and `State` string properties.

Basically what I want to do is look up the class `Person` in the current assembly and create an instance of it and assign all of the values, no matter how complicated the classes get, as long as at the deepest level they are composed of primitives, strings, and a few common structures such as `DateTime`.

I have a solution which allows me to assign the top level properties and down into one of the complex properties. I am assuming I must use recursion to solve this, but I would prefer not to.

Though, even with recursion, I am at a loss as to a nice way to get down into each of the properties and assign their values.

In this example below I am trying to translate the dotted representation to classes based on a method's parameters. I look up the appropriate dotted representation based on the parameter's type, trying to find a match. `DotField` is basically a `KeyValuePair<string, object>` where the key is the `Name` property. The code below may not work correctly but it should express the idea well enough.

```
foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in this.method.Parameters)
{
    Type parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;
    object parameterInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(parameterType);

    PropertyInfo[] properties = parameterType.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
        if (propertyType.IsPrimitive || propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            string propertyPath = String.Format("{0}.{1}", parameterType.Name, propertyType.Name);
            foreach (DotField df in this.DotFields)
            {
                if (df.Name == propertyPath)
                {
                    property.SetValue(parameterInstance, df.Value, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Somehow dive into the class, since it's a non-primitive
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your solution for top level properties?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Sure, that has been done now. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my complete code example. I decided to stay away from the crazy amount of reflection and mapping and get a lot of context information from the dotted list structure.

I want to thank `Tim` and `rla4` for their solutions and providing the information that brought me to this solution.

```
    private static int GetPathDepth(string path)
    {
        int depth = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            if (path[i] == '.')
            {
                depth++;
            }
        }

        return depth;
    }

    private static string GetPathAtDepth(string path, int depth)
    {
        StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        string[] pathParts = path.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < depth && i < pathParts.Length; i++)
        {
            string pathPart = pathParts[i];

            if (i == depth - 1 || i == pathParts.Length - 1)
            {
                pathBuilder.Append(pathPart);
            }
            else
            {
                pathBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}.", pathPart);
            }
        }

        string pathAtDepth = pathBuilder.ToString();
        return pathAtDepth;
    }

    private static string[] GetIntermediatePaths(string path)
    {
        int depth = GetPathDepth(path);

        string[] intermediatePaths = new string[depth];
        for (int i = 0; i < intermediatePaths.Length; i++)
        {
            string intermediatePath = GetPathAtDepth(path, i + 1);
            intermediatePaths[i] = intermediatePath;
        }

        return intermediatePaths;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetProperty(Type root, string path)
    {
        PropertyInfo result = null;

        string[] pathParts = path.Split('.');
        foreach (string pathPart in pathParts)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(result, null))
            {
                result = root.GetProperty(pathPart);
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.PropertyType.GetProperty(pathPart);
            }
        }

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(result, null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("A property at the specified path could not be located.", "path");
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static object GetParameter(ParameterInfo parameter, Dictionary<string, string> valueMap)
    {
        Type root = parameter.ParameterType;

        Dictionary<string, object> instanceMap = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> valueMapEntry in valueMap)
        {
            string path = valueMapEntry.Key;
            string value = valueMapEntry.Value;

            string[] intermediatePaths = GetIntermediatePaths(path);
            foreach (string intermediatePath in intermediatePaths)
            {
                PropertyInfo intermediateProperty = GetProperty(root, intermediatePath);

                object propertyTypeInstance;
                if (!instanceMap.TryGetValue(intermediatePath, out propertyTypeInstance))
                {
                    propertyTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(intermediateProperty.PropertyType);
                    instanceMap.Add(intermediatePath, propertyTypeInstance);
                }
            }

            PropertyInfo property = GetProperty(root, path);

            TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
            object convertedValue = converter.ConvertFrom(value);

            instanceMap.Add(path, convertedValue);
        }

        object rootInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(root);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> instanceMapEntry in instanceMap)
        {
            string path = instanceMapEntry.Key;
            object value = instanceMapEntry.Value;

            PropertyInfo property = GetProperty(root, path);

            object instance;
            int depth = GetPathDepth(path);
            if (depth == 0)
            {
                instance = rootInstance;
            }
            else
            {
                string parentPath = GetPathAtDepth(path, depth);
                instance = instanceMap[parentPath];
            }

            property.SetValue(instance, value);
        }

        return rootInstance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Dictionary` sounds similar to JSON-formatted data. If you first transform it into a compatible form, you can use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to convert the dictionary into your object. Here's an example of that:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"Person.Name", "John Doe"},
        {"Person.Age", 27},
        {"Person.Address.House", "123"},
        {"Person.Address.Street", "Fake Street"},
        {"Person.Address.City", "Nowhere"},
        {"Person.Address.State", "NH"},
    };
    var hierarchicalDict = GetItemAndChildren(dict, "Person");
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hierarchicalDict);
    Person person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
    // person has all of the values you'd expect
}
static object GetItemAndChildren(Dictionary<string, object> dict, string prefix = "")
{
    object val;
    if (dict.TryGetValue(prefix, out val))
        return val;
    else
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
            prefix += ".";
        var children = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var child in dict.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith(prefix)).Select(x => x.Key.Substring(prefix.Length).Split(new[] { '.' }, 2)[0]).Distinct())
        {
            children[child] = GetItemAndChildren(dict, prefix + child);
        }
        return children;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I still need to figure out how to match the dotted representation to the object hierarchy. I have a type composed of other types, so even getting it into the dictionary inside a dictionary form you have here is seemingly difficult.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray I've updated my answer with a method to make the dotted representation match the hierarchy. It didn't come out nearly as complicated and convoluted as I had feared, though there is room for improvement.

Comment: This doesn't immediately appear to support a hierarchy with duplicate property names. For example, if the top level class has a property named the same as another property, in a different complex class, lower in the hierarchy. Example: A.B.B. I am working with rewriting your method without LINQ, so that I can understand it better.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray works for me (I changed the `House` property name to `Address`, so I now have `{"Person.Address.Address", "123"}` and it works). I know that it won't work right if you have, e.g. both `Person.Address` and `Person.Address.State` (I don't see how that would make sense). The code I had at first had a lot of issues, are you sure you're using the code I have in my answer now?

Comment: It did work for all of my tests after I worked on expanding it to understand it without the LINQ stuff. Relying on Json.Net was something I wanted to avoid and I also needed to make sure I understood the whole process. It helped me get to my solution which I decided to use as the implementation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use reflection for doing so. I had fun writing this down :)

```
private object Eval(KeyValuePair<string, object> df)
{
    var properties = df.Key.Split('.');
    //line below just creates the root object (Person), you could replace it with whatever works in your example
    object root = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().First(t => t.Name == properties.First()));

    var temp = root;

    for (int i = 1; i < properties.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var propertyInfo = temp.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]);
        var propertyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);                
        propertyInfo.SetValue(temp, propertyInstance, null);

        temp = propertyInstance;
    }

    temp.GetType().GetProperty(properties.Last()).SetValue(temp, df.Value, null);
    return root;
}
```